# MOST RECENT VALUE (CAN ANYONE DO THIS)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, logic, duplicates

ive been told by my collegue to do this

"Perhaps what you can do is run a second table between #Basic and #Product where you only update the new retail column with the top 1 based on valid from desc for each currency code from #Basic?"

```
Create Table #Basic(
ProductCode Int,
ContractNo Int,
ProductDescription Varchar (max),
CGNo Nvarchar(MAX),
SCGNo Nvarchar(MAX),
EmpNo Int,
CurrencyCode NVARCHAR(MAX),
Retail decimal (38,  2),
ValidFrom datetime,
Active int,
ValidForCountry int
)

Insert Into #Basic


SELECT
c.ProductCode
,ContractNo
,p.Description
,p.CGNo
,p.SCGNo
,p.EmpNo
,r.CurrencyCode
,r.Retail
,r.ValidFrom
,p.active
,c.Validforcountry
FROM CONTRACT c
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT Distinct
ProductCode,
CurrencyCode,
Retail,
ValidFrom
From DIVRETAIL) as r on c.ProductCode = r.ProductCode
LEFT JOIN product p on c.ProductCode = p.ProductCode
WHERE ContractNo = 144546
And r.ValidFrom <= @enddate

SELECT Distinct
ProductCode,
CurrencyCode,
Retail,
ValidFrom
From DIVRETAIL
update #Basic 
set Retail =( 
select top 1 retail From DIVRETAIL



create table #basicretail
(ProductCode int
,ContractNo int
,Description varchar(MAX)
,CGNo int
,SCGNo int
,EmpNo int
,CurrencyCode varchar(10)
,Retail int
,ValidFrom datetime
,active int
,Validforcountry int
)


CREATE TABLE #Product
(
ProductCode Int,
ContractNo Int,
ProductDescription Varchar (max),
CGNo Nvarchar(MAX),
SCGNo Nvarchar(MAX),
EmpNo Int,
CurrencyCode NVARCHAR(MAX),
Retail decimal (38,  2),
ValidFrom datetime,
Active int,
ValidForCountry int,
Cost decimal (38,3)
)

INSERT INTO #Product
SELECT
ProductCode
,ContractNo
,ProductDescription 
,CGNo
,SCGNo
,EmpNo
,CurrencyCode
,Retail
,ValidFrom
,Active
,ValidForCountry
,NULL
FROM #basic

UPDATE #Product
SET #Product.Cost =
(CASE WHEN #Product.CurrencyCode = 'EUR' THEN
(SELECT TOP 1
Case when c.IncoTermtype IN (1,9) then b.DDP/p.Packsize
when c.IncoTermtype IN (2,12) then b.DAT/p.Packsize
when c.IncoTermtype = 10 then (b.FOB+b.Freight)/p.Packsize
when c.IncoTermtype = 13 then (b.ExWorks+Freight)/p.Packsize else 0 End as         Casecost 
FROM braketvalue b
LEFT JOIN CONTRACT c on b.ContractNo = c.ContractNo
LEFT JOIN PRODUCT p on c.ProductCode = p.ProductCode
WHERE ValidFrom <= @enddate
AND b.DivNo like '8__'
AND #Product.CurrencyCode = 'EUR'
AND #Product.ContractNo = b.ContractNo)
ELSE
(SELECT TOP 1
Case when c.IncoTermtype IN (1,9) then b.DDP/p.Packsize
when c.IncoTermtype IN (2,12) then b.DAT/p.Packsize
when c.IncoTermtype = 10 then (b.FOB+b.Freight)/p.Packsize
when c.IncoTermtype = 13 then (b.ExWorks+Freight)/p.Packsize else 0 End as     Casecost 
FROM braketvalue b
LEFT JOIN CONTRACT c on b.ContractNo = c.ContractNo
LEFT JOIN PRODUCT p on c.ProductCode = p.ProductCode
WHERE ValidFrom <= @enddate
AND b.DivNo like '7__'
AND #Product.CurrencyCode = '£'
AND #Product.ContractNo = b.ContractNo)
END
)
```

Comment: Move the r and p conditions from WHERE clause to ON clauses to get true LEFT JOIN.

Comment: @Jarlh please re review the question

Comment: In general, if a table is right side argument to a left join, put the table's conditions in the ON clause.

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to say `>=` instead like

```
WHERE 
 r.ValidFrom >= '2015-01-07'
```

As well, move the conditions from `WHERE` clause to `JOIN ON` clause

```
From DIVTAIL) as r on c.ProductCode = r.ProductCode
AND r.ValidFrom >= '2015-01-07'
LEFT JOIN product p on c.ProductCode = p.ProductCode
AND p.CGNo = '01' AND p.SCGNo = '01' AND p.ProductCode = 3317
```

Comment: Perhaps what you can do is run a second table between #Basic and #Product where you only update the new retail column with the top 1 based on valid from desc for each currency code from #Basic?

Comment: @Cladback, bit confused here. Are you asking me (or) confirming something (or) suggesting this is what you have done?

Comment: my boss told me to do that but i dont know how

Comment: your script didnt work so i asked my bos and that is how he wants it done

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want an exact date you might have to do something like a date range that is calculated based on the date passed in. So your JOIN would be like LEFT JOIN ON date between BeginningDate and EndDate

Comment: please re review the question